# CountryData function

Tags: curated-data

I under that Mathematica are able to extract data from a cloud/ online sources. Pardon the improper use of jargon for programming and IT is not my area of familiarity.

Are the data that Mathematica is able to extract limited? I am interested in, for instance, extracting the number of hospitals and clinics within a country, and, number of person above a certain age in a country.

Would Mathematica be able to achieve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking just about the data curated by Wolfram, or about importing data from any source on the web?  See `Import[]` for the latter.

Comment: Curated. But your question ignited my light-bulb. If the information I seek is in a PDF on the web, would important be able to extract only a certain paragraph from that PDF?@MichaelE2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the data that Mathematica is able to obtain via CountryData and other curated data functions is limited. The data is *curated*, which means that it is assembled by WRI from a variety of sources, and you only have access (via this mechanism) to data that WRI has made available. You can find a good description of the available properties in the Details section of the [`CountryData` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html), or a straight list using `CountryData[country, "Properties"]`.

In your case, there doesn't seem to be any count of hospitals in the health-related data, and the demographic properties don't seem to be detailed enough for your needs, so you'll probably need to look elsewhere for the data.